# Turtle build:android running into error (expo 37)

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I'm an expo/turtle noob. my build is failing with the following

```
Oct 20 10:49:22 turtle[34364] ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'package' of undefined
    at runShellAppModificationsAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.13/src/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:441:40)
    at Object.createAndroidShellAppAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.13/src/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:376:9)
    at runShellAppBuilder (/home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/builders/android.ts:91:5)
    at buildAndroid (/home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/builders/android.ts:23:26)
    at /home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/bin/utils/builder.ts:87:7
    at Command.<anonymous> (/home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/bin/index.ts:23:12)
  platform: "android"
Oct 20 10:49:22 turtle[34364] ERROR: Failed to build standalone app
  err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'package' of undefined
      at runShellAppModificationsAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.13/src/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:441:40)
      at Object.createAndroidShellAppAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.13/src/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:376:9)
      at runShellAppBuilder (/home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/builders/android.ts:91:5)
      at buildAndroid (/home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/builders/android.ts:23:26)
      at /home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/bin/utils/builder.ts:87:7
      at Command.<anonymous> (/home/mulaiko/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/src/bin/index.ts:23:12)
  platform: "android"
```

Could you please help me make sense of this error and assist in my solving the issue?